# How to share cookies between in-app browser and React Native (iOS)?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I am trying to implement SSO in a mobile app.

I am using [react-native-inappbrowser-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn) to handle the SSO auth flow in an in-app browser. I can successfully authenticate inside the in-app browser.  That is to say, I receive a session cookie and I can view the web version of the app from inside of the in-app browser.   However, when I redirect back to the mobile application, none of my `fetch` requests include the session cookie!  I have `fetch` configured with `{credentials: 'include'}`.   `CookieManager.getAll()` returns an empty object.

I am experiencing this problem on iOS (v15.2), and I have yet to test on Android.

According to the documentation I should be able to share the cookie set in the in the in-app browser with my react-native app.

I am using the following code based off of the react-native-inappbrowser-reborn documentation

```
async function authenticate() {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/sso/login?redirect_uri=myapp://home';
  const deepLink = 'myapp://home';
  try {
    if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
      InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, deepLink, {
        // iOS Properties
        ephemeralWebSession: false,
        // Android Properties
        showTitle: false,
        enableUrlBarHiding: true,
        enableDefaultShare: false,
      }).then(async (response) => {
        if (response.type === 'success' && response.url) {
          console.log('should see a new cookie set!');
          console.log(await CookieManager.getAll()); // Sadly, nothing in here

          const user = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/user', {
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          });
          /* This is an authenticated endpoint which returns a 401,
           because for some reason the session cookie doesn't go along with the request */
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error('login unsuccessful');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Any bit of insight here would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: This is likely an issue with React Native itself: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#known-issues-with-fetch-and-cookie-based-authentication

I have same case and have no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: @ivts I initially had a false assumption that the inAppBrowser and ReactNative would share cookies.  That is not the case.  What I did was I returned a redirectURL from the InAppBrowser in the form of a custom app URL i.e `myApp://somePath`.   The inAppBrowser will close when it sees this customURL and then the application can handle the customURL instead of the inAppBrowser.  The customURL will have something like an authorization_code as a query string param which can be used to identify the user that just performed an SSO login in the inAppBrowser

Comment: The crucial part is that your application itself is the one that initiates the login request.   Do not send the login request from within the inappbrowser

Comment: Yes, you can pass in the needed data by the query params in the callback. Is it the way you did? Or have you found a way to share cookies by any chance?